# Android - Can't display Textview dynamically in LinearLayout

Tags: android, textview

This is xml code:

```
<ScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DeleteActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is a portion of java code:

```
    LinearLayout linear_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[count];
    do {
        myTextViews[pointer] = new TextView(this);
        myTextViews[pointer].setText(getResources().getString(R.string.data_dd) + data + "\n");
        linear_layout.addView(myTextViews[pointer]);
        pointer++;
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

The problem is that is shown only the first textview. If i use a relative layout instead of a linear layout it show me all the text view but one on each other. How can i do?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I think you should change the orientation of the `LinearLayout` to `verical`. Also `TextView`s you are dinamically creating have not `LayoutParams`

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

  do {
       myTextViews[pointer] = new TextView(this);
       myTextViews[pointer].setText(getResources().getString(R.string.data_dd) + data + "\n");
       linear_layout.addView(myTextViews[pointer], layoutParams);
       pointer++;
  } while(c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: thx, it works :) previously i added android:orientation="vertical" only into scrollview and not in linear layout.

Comment: One question: and if i use a Relative Layout how can i solve the problem of overlay textview?

Comment: RelativeLayout need that every child specify its position. you can specify this position with the addRule method of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, for instance: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

Comment: in this way the textview are always overlay each other

Comment: you shoud set a Position for every textview. If you set for ALIGN_PARENT_TOP to all the textview of course they will overlap. You should read the documentation

Comment: is there a way to set the parameter "below" to a textview? In this way i could set the second textview under the previous and so on...